# p3p Policy on wordpress response not sending the policy

Tags: wordpress, iis, p3p

I have created the p3p files, placed them in the w3c folder but fiddler2 still returns sets cookies without p3p?

Wordpress site on iis...

trying to get it to return sets cookies & P3P...

I know this is old stuff but client wants it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this line to the header.php and it sent the proper information in the header.

```
<?php language_attributes();
```

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
 ?>>

After that fiddler2 was green.